# HP NC523SFP no link detected

Tags: hp-proliant, dell-poweredge, 10gbethernet, sfp, qlogic

I have two HP NC523SFP 10Gb 2-port (1 on a HP DL380e Gen8 and the other on Dell PowerEdge 2950) both systems have Centos 7, the cards are detect and are running the same firmware.
I have connected directly the servers with 10Gtek SFP-H10GB-CU2M cable which according to some other posts found online looks compatible (I've tried also with 10Gtek SFP-H10GB-CU2M cable) but the problem is that the link is not detected between the two cards.. On the other two slots of these cards I have the fiber adapters 10Gtek AXS85-192-M3-Cisco2 these are connected to a Cisco switch with an LC-SC fiber cable but neither these gets the link detected.
Here the ethtool output from both servers:

DL380e Gen8 (seems that both fiber and copper transreceiver are recognized)

```
[root@hpe ~]# ifconfig ens4f0
ens4f0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 8c:dc:d4:91:5e:50  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 90

[root@hpe ~]# ifconfig ens4f1
ens4f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 8c:dc:d4:91:5e:54  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 91

[root@hpe ~]# ethtool ens4f0
Settings for ens4f0:
        Supported ports: [ TP FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000000 (0)
        Link detected: no

[root@hpe ~]# ethtool ens4f1
Settings for ens4f1:
        Supported ports: [ TP FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000000 (0)
        Link detected: no
```

Dell PowerEdge 2950

```
[root@dell ~]# ifconfig enp8s0f0
enp8s0f0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether c4:34:6b:cc:cf:60  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 31

[root@dell ~]# ifconfig enp8s0f1
enp8s0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether c4:34:6b:cc:cf:64  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 32

[root@dell ~]# ethtool enp8s0f0
Settings for enp8s0f0:
        Supported ports: [ TP FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: Other
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000000 (0)    
        Link detected: no

[root@dell ~]# ethtool enp8s0f1
Settings for enp8s0f1:
        Supported ports: [ TP FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000000 (0)
        Link detected: no
```

What can I check? I have tried to force the link speed but I get "Operation not permitted"
I noticed that on the Dell the copper cable is detected as "Port: Other"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it's the port enp8s0f0 on Dell 2950 broken.. I have moved the DAC cable on enp8s0f1 and I have the link now.
The test to determinate this was:

- Looping the DAC cable on HP -> Link OK
- Looping the DAC cable on Dell -> Link KO